# Create simple User-Interface via code using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to create a simple login form (Username / Password) for a demo using Xamarin.iOS, but I would prefer not having to dive into XCode for this at this moment.

Maybe something similar to what you can do in other .NET technologies:

```
var panel = new Panel();
panel.Controls.Add(new Label("Username"));
panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox("Password"));
```

Is there a way to create simple interfaces in Xamarin for iOS programatically?
Or it is required to design the interfaces using XCode only?

Comment: There's an introduction to the topic of creating xibless ui's and several follow on links on http://blog.xamarin.com/creating-imperative-uis-in-c/

Comment: If you need a login in form with code I would suggest taking a look att this page, http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/create_a_login_window_using_monotouch.dialog Where you can find a nice tutorial to do exactly what you're looking for, there's also sample code to download. And yes, it's perfectly fine to use that in production, as long as you handle security yourself and not using hard coded username/password that they do in the example. ;-)

Comment: Nice tutorial. Thanks for the hard-coding tip. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can create UI via code.  Using XCode's designer is entirely optional.

```cs
UIButton btn = new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);         
btn.SetTitle ("Hello", UIControlState.Normal);
 btn.Frame = new RectangleF (50, 50, 50, 50);          

btn.TouchDown += delegate {     
      UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Hello", "Hello, Xamarin!", null, "OK");
       alert.Show();
   };

 this.View.AddSubview (btn);
```

For data entry UI, you may also want to consider using [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog).

Comment: For android-like layout (a bit like xaml layout too) also consider https://github.com/toptensoftware/XibFree

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little late to the game, but have you tried just using a UIAlertView and then doing:

```
yourAlertView.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput;
```

It'll create a popup login window with the textfields already setup for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    currentTF = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    [self createLoginUI];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
-(void)createLoginUI
{
    //For My Label
    UILabel *MyLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 20)];
    MyLabel.text = @"My Login Screen";
    MyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    MyLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    MyLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    MyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [self.view addSubview:MyLabel];


    //For Email Label
    UILabel *emailLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 50, 20)];
    emailLabel.text = @"Email:";
    emailLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    emailLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [self.view addSubview:emailLabel];

    //For Email UITextField
    emailTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 40, 200, 30)];
    [emailTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    emailTF.delegate = self;
    emailTF.tag = 101;
    [self.view addSubview:emailTF];

    //For Password Label
    UILabel *passwordLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 100, 20)];
    passwordLabel.text = @"Password:";
    passwordLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    passwordLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [self.view addSubview:passwordLabel];

    //For Password UITextField
    passwordTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 80, 180, 30)];
    passwordTF.secureTextEntry = YES;
    passwordTF.delegate = self;
    passwordTF.tag = 102;
    [passwordTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [self.view addSubview:passwordTF];

    //For Login Button
    UIButton *loginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [loginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    loginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(120, 130, 50, 20);
    loginBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [loginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loginBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:loginBtn];

    //For Forgot Password Button
    UIButton *forgotPasswdBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [forgotPasswdBtn setTitle:@"Forgot Password" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    forgotPasswdBtn.frame = CGRectMake(30, 170, 120, 20);
    forgotPasswdBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [forgotPasswdBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(forgotPasswordBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:forgotPasswdBtn];


    //For sign up Button
    UIButton *signUpBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [signUpBtn setTitle:@"SignUp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    signUpBtn.frame = CGRectMake(170, 170, 60, 20);
    signUpBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [signUpBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(signUpBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:signUpBtn];


    //For remember Me
    UIButton *remBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [remBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    remBtn.frame = CGRectMake(90, 130, 20, 20);
    [remBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(remBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:remBtn];


}
-(void)loginBtnClick
{
    [currentTF resignFirstResponder];
    if ([self validateLoginScreen])
    {
        //To clear textFields
        emailTF.text= @"";
        passwordTF.text = @"";
        //For Home View
        homeViewObj = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [homeViewObj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:homeViewObj];

        //For Logout Button
        UIButton *logOutBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [logOutBtn setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        logOutBtn.frame = CGRectMake(170, 170, 60, 20);
        //        logOutBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [logOutBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(logOutBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [homeViewObj addSubview:logOutBtn];

    }

}
-(void)forgotPasswordBtnClick
{

    UIAlertView *alertview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" message:@"please enter sequrity qustion" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    alertview.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alertview textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate=self;
    [alertview show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertview2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Reset password" message:@"new password is send to your mail id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [alertview2 show];
    }

}


-(void)signUpBtnClick
{

    //[currentTF resignFirstResponder];
    viewobjsignup=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [viewobjsignup setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:viewobjsignup];
    UILabel *MyLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 20)];
        MyLabel.text = @"Register Here";
    MyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        MyLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        MyLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
       MyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
        [viewobjsignup addSubview:MyLabel];

    //username
    UILabel *usernmobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 100, 20)];
    usernmobj.text=@"UserName";
    usernmobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    usernmobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    usernmobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
   usernmobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:usernmobj];

    userTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 40, 150, 30)];
    //userTF.secureTextEntry = YES;
    userTF.delegate = self;
   // userTF.tag = 102;
    [userTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:userTF];

    userTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;


    //email id
    UILabel *Emailnmobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 80, 20)];
    Emailnmobj.text=@"Email Id";
    Emailnmobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    Emailnmobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Emailnmobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    Emailnmobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:Emailnmobj];

    EmailTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 80, 150, 30)];
   //EmailTF.secureTextEntry = YES;
    EmailTF.delegate = self;
  // EmailTF.tag = 102;
    [EmailTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:EmailTF];
     EmailTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;


    //password
    UILabel *passnmobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,120,100,20)];
    passnmobj.text=@"Password";
    passnmobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    passnmobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    passnmobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    passnmobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:passnmobj];

    pwdTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 120, 170, 30)];
    pwdTF.secureTextEntry = YES;
    pwdTF.delegate = self;
   // pwdTF.tag = 102;
    [pwdTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:pwdTF];
     pwdTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;


    //conform password
    UILabel *comfobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,160,100,20)];
    comfobj.text=@"Confpass";
    //comfobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    comfobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    comfobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    comfobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:comfobj];

    comfTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 160, 180, 30)];
    comfTF.secureTextEntry = YES;
    comfTF.delegate = self;
   // comfTF.tag = 102;
    [comfTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:comfTF];
     comfTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;


    //for dob
    UILabel *Dboobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 190, 140, 20)];


    Dboobj.text=@"DOB";
    Dboobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    Dboobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Dboobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    Dboobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:Dboobj];


    //textfiels for date

    UITextField *dateobj=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 210, 90, 30)];
    [dateobj setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    dateobj.placeholder=@"Date";
    [dateobj setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    dateobj.tag=105;
    dateobj.delegate=self;
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:dateobj];
     dateobj.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

//    //txtfield for DOB_date
//    UITextField * dob_dateLab=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 270, 90, 30)];
//    [dob_dateLab setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
//    dob_dateLab.placeholder=@"Date";
//    [dob_dateLab setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
//    dob_dateLab.tag=104;
//    dob_dateLab.delegate = self;
//    [viewobjsignup addSubview:dob_dateLab];

    //txtfield for month
    UITextField * monthobj=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 210, 90, 30)];
    [monthobj setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    monthobj.delegate = self;
    [monthobj setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    monthobj.tag=106;
    monthobj.placeholder=@"Month";
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:monthobj];
     monthobj.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

    //txtfield for year
    UITextField * yearobj=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 210, 90, 30)];
    [yearobj setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    yearobj.delegate = self;
    [yearobj setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    yearobj.tag=107;
    yearobj.placeholder=@"Year";
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:yearobj];
     yearobj.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

    //for label gender
    UILabel *genderobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 240, 80, 20)];

   genderobj.text=@"Gender";
    genderobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    genderobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    genderobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
   genderobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:genderobj];


    //for male

    UILabel *maleobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 240, 40, 20)];

    maleobj.text=@"male";
    maleobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    maleobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    maleobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    maleobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:maleobj];


    //for female

    UILabel *femaleobj=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 240, 80, 20)];

    femaleobj.text=@"Female";
    femaleobj.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    femaleobj.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    femaleobj.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
    femaleobj.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:femaleobj];


    //for male radio but
    malebut=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [malebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_check.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[malebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobutton-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    malebut.frame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 20, 20);
    [malebut addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnClick_male) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:malebut];


    //For female radio but
    femalebut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [ femalebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_uncheck.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     femalebut.frame = CGRectMake(270, 240, 20, 20);
    [ femalebut addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnClick_female) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:femalebut];




    //For Save button
    UIButton * savebut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [savebut setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    savebut.titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    savebut.frame = CGRectMake(90, 430, 70, 20);
    [savebut addTarget:self action:@selector(saveBtnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:savebut];


    //For cancel button
    UIButton * cancelBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    cancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(150, 430, 60, 20);
    [cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cancelBtn.titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    cancelBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelBtnClick1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewobjsignup addSubview:cancelBtn];

    //register button
//    UIButton *registerbut=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//    [registerbut setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [registerbut setFrame:CGRectMake(20,200,160,20)];
//    [registerbut addTarget:self action:@selector(Registerclick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//    [viewobjsignup addSubview:registerbut];


//    //labal
//    myleb=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,160,140,20)];
//    //comfobj.text=@" ConfermPassword";
//    myleb.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
//     myleb.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//     myleb.backgroundColor=[UIColor cyanColor];
//     myleb.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
//    [self.view addSubview: myleb];


}



-(void)radioBtnClick_female
{


    [femalebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_check.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [malebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_uncheck.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


-(void)radioBtnClick_male
{


    [femalebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_uncheck.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [malebut setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_check.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}



-(void)logOutBtnClick
{
    [homeViewObj removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)remBtnClick
{

}


-(void)cancelBtnClick1
{
    [viewobjsignup removeFromSuperview];

}

-(void)saveBtnClick
{
    [currentTF resignFirstResponder];

    [self validregister];

}


-(void)validregister
{
    if(userTF.text.length==00||pwdTF.text.length==00||comfTF.text.length==00)

    {
        [self  showAlertMessage:@"Please enter all nesessary field"];

    }
    else if([self emailValidation:EmailTF.text]==NO)


        {
            [self showAlertMessage:@"Please enter valid email address"];
            EmailTF.text=@"";

        }
    else if([pwdTF.text isEqual:comfTF.text]==NO)
    {
        [self showAlertMessage:@"password mismatch"];
        // userTf.text=@"";
        comfTF.text=@"";

    }
    else
    {

            EmailTF.text=@"";
            pwdTF.text=@"";
            [user setObject:EmailTF.text forKey:@"username plist"];

            [user setObject:pwdTF.text forKey:@"password plist"];


            [user synchronize];
            [self showAlertMessage:@"You are REGISTERED now"];
            [viewobjsignup removeFromSuperview];



    }



}

//-(void)Registerclick
//{
//    UIAlertView *alertview1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Your registration is successful..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//    [alertview1 show];
//    [viewobjsignup removeFromSuperview]; 
//}
//
#pragma mark Validation Method
-(BOOL)validateLoginScreen
{
    if (emailTF.text.length==0)
    {
        [self  showAlertMessage:@"Please enter email address"];
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([self emailValidation:emailTF.text]==NO)
    {
        [self showAlertMessage:@"Please enter valid email address"];
        return NO;

    }
    else if (passwordTF.text.length==0)
    {
        [self showAlertMessage:@"Please enter password "];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
-(void)showAlertMessage:(NSString *)msg
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Note" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
-(BOOL) emailValidation:(NSString *)emailTxt
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailTxt];

}
#pragma mark TextField Delegates
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
//    if(textField.tag==101)
//    {
//        [passwordTF becomeFirstResponder];
//    }
//    else if(textField.tag==102)
//    {
//        [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];
//    }
    [currentTF resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;



}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [currentTF resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    currentTF = textField;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    currentTF = textField;

    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}

-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
    int movementDistance = 0; // tweak as needed

    if (textField.tag==105||textField.tag
        ==106||textField.tag==107)
    {
        movementDistance = -130;
    }
    else
    {
        movementDistance = 00;

    }
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, or if the code is useful.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, some description of what your code does might help the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin 5.10:**

```
    UIButton sampleButton1;
    UITextField sampleTextField1;
    UITextField sampleTextField2;



    public void addUIButtonToView ()
            {           
                this.sampleButton1 = new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);   
                sampleButton1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (10f, 100f, 300f, 50f);
                this.sampleButton1.SetTitle ("Sample Button", UIControlState.Normal);
                this.sampleButton1.SetNeedsLayout ();
                sampleButton1.TouchUpInside += OnSpeakButtonTapped;

                this.View.AddSubview (sampleButton1);
            }

            void OnSpeakButtonTapped (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // This is the event handler for the actual UIButton TouchUpInside event.   
                Console.WriteLine ("button tapped");
            }

public void addUITextFieldToView ()
        {
            //Initiate UITextField Delegates
            sampleTextField1 = new UITextField ();
            sampleTextField1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (10f, 100f, 300f, 50f);
            //sampleTextField1.Text = "This is Xamarin iOS TextField";
            sampleTextField1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
            sampleTextField1.Alpha = 1.0f;
            sampleTextField1.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            sampleTextField1.Font = UIFont.FromName (name: "Arial", size: 15f);

            sampleTextField1.Placeholder = "Enter text here";
            sampleTextField1.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress;
            sampleTextField1.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Default;
            sampleTextField1.MinimumFontSize = 17f;
            sampleTextField1.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

            //Additional
            sampleTextField2 = new UITextField ();
            sampleTextField2.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (this.View.Frame.X + 5, this.View.Frame.Y + 250, this.View.Frame.Width - 10, this.View.Frame.Height / 3);
            sampleTextField2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromFile ("Real-Estate_4.jpg"));
            sampleTextField2.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true; 
            sampleTextField2.MinimumFontSize = 12f;

            //Setting Boarder and curved edges
            sampleTextField2.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
            sampleTextField2.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
            sampleTextField2.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;

            //Shadows
            sampleTextField2.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
            sampleTextField2.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize (3f, 3f);
            sampleTextField2.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.3f;
            sampleTextField2.Layer.ShadowRadius = 3f;

            this.View.AddSubview (sampleTextField1);
            this.View.AddSubview (sampleTextField2);

            //Adding Delegate Methods
            this.enableUITextFieldDelegateMethods ();

        }
void enableUITextFieldDelegateMethods ()
        {
            this.sampleTextField1.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
                sampleTextField2.BecomeFirstResponder ();
                textField.ResignFirstResponder ();
                return true;
            };

            this.sampleTextField1.ShouldBeginEditing += (textField) => {
                //Write here
                return true;
            };

            this.sampleTextField1.ShouldEndEditing += (textField) => {
                //Write here
                return true;
            };
            this.sampleTextField1.ShouldClear += (textField) => {
                //Write here
                return true;
            };

            this.sampleTextField1.ShouldChangeCharacters = (UITextField txt, NSRange range, string sampleTxt) => {
                var newLength = txt.Text.Length + sampleTxt.Length - range.Length;
                return newLength <= 9;

            };
        }
```